# Should quotation marks be used where a quote has been deliberately changed to mean something slightly different?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I'm writing a blog post where I present a direct quote, then present a quote slightly altered to **deliberately** change what the initial quote means. I am presenting the slightly altered quote as an example of how the feel of a news might change but the facts stay the same, if read ignoring gender where possible. Below is an extract from the blog post where i give the example.

> I would suggest reading either article with a twist - whenever you
>   see a job position qualified by the predominant gender of workers in
>   that role, ignore the gendered qualifier. For example, from the BBC’s
>   article:
>
> “Lawyers say hourly-paid female store staff earn less than men even
>   though the value of the work is comparable.”
>
> Would become…
>
> “Lawyers say hourly-paid store staff earn less than warehouse staff
>   even though the value of the work is comparable.”

How should the second 'quote' be presented now it does not entirely reflect the source article, but is still mostly sourced from the article?

Comment: If you're using the original to lend support to the claim in the second sentence, it's a misquote. If you're just modelling one sentence on another, it's neither a quote nor a misquote (but at some stage might become plagiarism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotation marks are used to enclose not only quotations from real sources (i.e. the words that somebody has actually said or written somewhere else), but also ‘quotations’ from imaginary ‘sources’, such as the words ‘spoken’ by an imaginary character, or the words that are given as examples of something that somebody (who needn’t be specified) *could* say. This last way of using them can be seen throughout this site.

The second sentence that appears in quotation marks in the OP’s example is an instance of that, perfectly correct, use of quotation marks. The OP is, in that example, merely inviting his readers to think about that sentence, while making it clear that no actual source is being quoted. It is immaterial to the correctness of this use of quotation marks that the sentence is formed by modifying the actual quotation that precedes it. Of course when one does something like what OP is doing here, it is very important that the context make it clear which quotations are actual and which are the modifications; in OP’s example that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you alter a quote, you generally use square brackets to indicate the portion you have added. [This](https://writingcommons.org/open-text/research-methods-methodologies/integrate-evidence/incorporate-evidence/453-inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation) page provides detail on usage. And then ellipses for portions you have removed. [This](https://writingcommons.org/open-text/research-methods-methodologies/integrate-evidence/incorporate-evidence/613-omitting-words-from-a-direct-quotation-mla) page provides detail on usage.

So your quote would become “Lawyers say hourly-paid … store staff earn less than … [warehouse staff] even though the value of the work is comparable.”

However, as per the link above, '**A word of caution:** Bracketed insertions may not be used to alter or add to the quotation in a way that inaccurately or unfairly represents the original text. Quite simply, do not use bracketed material in a way that twists the author’s meaning.'

I would argue that you shouldn't use this quote at all, as you aren't even twisting the meaning of the original quote, you're completely changing it. As you've emboldened the word 'deliberately', you're clearly aware of what you're doing, and so presumably aware that you're on rocky ground. You might want to edit your question to explain to other users why you're misquoting, so you don't get numerous responses pointing out that you're on rocky ground.

Comment: I agree, it is not proper or ethical to change the meaning of what somebody has said and then present it as what they said. That is ‘misrepresentation’.

Comment: Have added more of an explanation to the question. My aim is not not misquote or mislead, merely to ask the reader to re-read the bbc article in a different way

Comment: @NedGrady much clearer, I would say just put it in quotes if it's clear in your blog what you're doing, why you're doing it, and the modified quote isn't directly attributed to the source. But, be interested to hear other opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the conversation. Context is important here. From the original quote that you cite, there is no indication that the male staff work only in the warehouse, and the female staff work only in the store. Unless specified elsewhere in the cited article, that is an odd assumption.

That said, I would use the quotation marks for the new version of the quote, simply to separate it from the rest of the blog post, given that you have made it clear that this is a different version of the original quote.

Comment: Everything in the quotation marks should be a direct word-for-word transcription, except when denoted by a "..." and other well-known techniques. It's not correct to misquote someone.